# GUI for making Tesseract-OCR 5 training files from existing images of text?

Tags: computer-vision, tesseract, training-data

I have some (19th century printed) text that has non-standard domain-specific symbols in it that Tesseract currently does not detect as letters. I want some software that will:

1. break the text into lines
2. add Tesseract's current best guess for the transcription of each line
3. let me correct the text through a GUI
4. spit out image-file/text-file pairs into some directory from where I can use it to fine-tune one of Tesseract's existing models.

If I were using Tesseract 3, then qt-box-editor would have been the thing to use; but I'm using Tesseract 5. Any software should be runnable under Linux. I'm happy to do some plumbing and minor coding but obviously I'd rather avoid building an annotation suite from scratch.

Tried VietOCR and it seems only to OCR complete pages rather than break into image files representing individual lines that can be annotated separately.